# How to upload image file from django admin panel ?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-models, django-admin

I am making a personal website using django 1.10
I want to upload my website logo from admin for why I can edit this in future. So that I have wrote website app and the models of website is :

from **future** import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class Website(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.ImageField(max_length=255, upload_to='images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Admin panel:
[image]

But image is not uploaded in `media/images` folder.
Please help me about this issue.

Comment: did you set up `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings.py?

Comment: Here is my media settings:

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

Comment: What is wrong I did ?

Comment: all looks fine.

Comment: I noticed that all images are uploaded outside of my project folder.

Comment: How to upload images inside my project folder?

Comment: ah so upload works fine, then just change you `MEDIA_ROOT` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves inside project folder if I change this in settings.py:

Before:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

After:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT), "media_cdn")
```

Comment: Now , images are uploaded but I can not render image in my view.html.

Here is the view code:

```<img class="mesmall" src="{{ website.logo.url }}" alt="tanbir">```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I solved this problem, I had to change urls.py as like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', include("website.urls", namespace='home')),
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    ]

    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```